# How to place spaces properly in nested dropdown in blade template Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. I recently started doing some basic things with Laravel and i really like it. I am trying to create nested dropdown like this:

[image]

From this dropdown list i will be selecting one.

I have my array like this:

[image]

And now my VIEW template look like below code, where i have used recursive method.

```
<select class="form-control select2me" name="service_id">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        @foreach($serviceslist as $serviceli)
             @include('services.categorydropdown', array('serviceli'=> $serviceli))
        @endforeach
</select>
```

Another template `services.categorydropdown`:

```
<option value="{{$serviceli['id']}}">
    @for ($i = 0; $i <= $serviceli['service_id']; $i++)
        @if($serviceli['service_id'] != 0)
        &nbsp; <!-- ------------I want to add Space as the nested level goes by ------------- -->
        @endif
    @endfor
    {{$serviceli['servicename']}}
</option>

@if(count($serviceli['allChildrenCategory']) > 0)
    @foreach($serviceli['allChildrenCategory'] as $serviceli)
        @include('services.categorydropdown', $serviceli)
    @endforeach
@endif
```

**Please suggest how can i create the space (`&nbsp;`) as the array level get nested.**

Thank you!

Thank you for your help. After your suggestion @nakashu here is how it looks now.
[image]
In last node we are going wrong somewhere.

Comment: Inside your if condition, what happens if you do `&nbsp` ? It give spaces or not ?

Comment: In this service id is the parent_id. So basically this is just a temporary method for short level.

Comment: But i would suggest you do have `Form::select` and have class to make it fine..

Comment: So, instead of doing foreach , why not you make the array to be iterated the filtered one ?

Comment: Can you suggest any example or any code example?

Comment: Sure, writing for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should solve it:

```
<select class="form-control select2me" name="service_id">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        @foreach($serviceslist as $serviceli)
             @include('services.categorydropdown', array('serviceli'=> $serviceli, 'level' => 0))
        @endforeach
</select>
```

Another template services.categorydropdown:

```
<option value="{{$serviceli['id']}}">
    @for ($i = 0; $i <= $level; $i++)            
        &nbsp;
    @endfor
    {{$serviceli['servicename']}}
</option>

@if(count($serviceli['allChildrenCategory']) > 0)
    @foreach($serviceli['allChildrenCategory'] as $serviceli)
        @include('services.categorydropdown', array('serviceli'=>$serviceli, 'level' => ($level + 1)))
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: You can use str_repeat("&nbsp;", $level); instead FOR

Comment: I just use the way you mentioned i guess we are just very close. Just the array is creating mistake in some where. I am attaching image for you in the question again in the bottom.

Comment: thanks .. didnt your blade ever so didnt know what allowed :) .. will edit

Comment: I just added the result view.

Comment: Fixed the code moved the level iteration outside of the children loop. Don't know if it valid blade syntax so edit as necesary

Comment: `jelly Beans` Didnt get the space. Means level 2 or more wont be having space in this method.

Comment: I guess i got it resolved. Let me check with one more node in that...:)

Comment: Ok what i did is `@include('services.categorydropdown', array('serviceli'=>$serviceli, 'level' => ($level + 1)))`

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you do those filters in your controller or model itself and just do the rendering in your blade.

```
{{ Form::select('service_id', $serviceslist, null, array('class' => 'form-control yourspacing')) }}
```

And write the style for your class

.yourspacing
{
//your required spacing
}

**Why do i want to do the filter in controller ?**

Because drastically doing such thing in blade is never a best practice.

**How can i do this ?**

By joining tables or array_filter. Depending of your filter

**Tip :** Always follow helpers the recommended way to get best performance.

**Update :**

As you want to do inner loop and check some condition. You shall just do `&nbsp;` as nakashu suggests

Comment: Yes because in any of the way, printing array in the select i never did. And data i am getting is in the representation like above image i mentioned at number 2.

Comment: Ahm,, But i always don't recommend to do in view, I would have used something like [this](https://github.com/lavary/laravel-menu)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I guess your are right. And menu module is a really nice module. I have to still check it, how it works. I am newbie to this :) But definitely you got a point, i shouldn't be doing this approach.